# Правильно ли так писать запросы в БД Laravel 8

Tags: mysql, laravel

Всем привет, не так давно работаю с Laravel и еще не все понял. Больше всего трудностей вызывает для меня передача переменной во вьюхи. К примеру у меня из одной таблицы данные выводят в 2 вьюхи, как правильно будет передавать в них переменные? Вот у меня есть:

```
  public function home(){
    return view('home');
  }
  public function products($product = null){
    $proditem = Product::where('id', '1')->get();
    return view('products', compact('proditem'));
  }
```

Я в products через compact передал переменную, но эти же данные нужно и в home передать, как это правильно сделать? Не дублировать тот же запрос из БД в home? Или добавить такие переменные во ViewComposer?
В ютубе видел чувак прям во вьюхе писал запрос, типа:

```
    @foreach(App\Models\Product::all() as $prod)
       {{$prod->name}}
    @endforeach
```

Насколько правильно так делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Второй вариант записи лучше не использовать

Если в вашем контроллере все методы используют какую-то переменную, можно вынести её в конструктор:

```
  private $products;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->products = Product::all();
  }
```

А позже передавать в функцию `view` посредством $this->products

```
  public function home(){
    return view('home', ['products' => $this->products]);
  }

  public function products($product = null){
    return view('products', ['products' => $this->products]);
  }
```

Однако, если вы используете эту переменную не во всех методах контроллера, лучше создавать её отдельно в каждом методе, чтобы избежать ненужных запросов к БД

Comment: а еще лучше __construct(Product $product) .... В Laravel замечательная реализация  IoC.